# How can I make a client use a VPN as its Internet gateway?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, connection

I have a client PC. I want it to connect to a VPN. However, the client either doesn't use the VPN's IP, or it doesn't use the VPN to connect to the Internet the way an anonymous VPN would. Instead, it uses its own IP and its own Internet connection to connect to the Internet and see the VPN. How can I make the client connect to the Internet only through my VPN? In other words, how can I make my VPN the client's Internet gateway?

Comment: You have to be connected to the internet or be connected to the same network as the VPN in order to use the VPN in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to route all your traffic to your VPN, maybe [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/e7ffd694-8f13-4287-b0cf-d70d4ada79ca) will help.